# Postman Testing - JSON - iterate over response with duplicate keys with different values

Tags: javascript, json, api, testing, postman

I'm new to the postman testing and i have found this case. I have this response

```
{
    "company": [
        {
            "publicKey": "40",
            "mutkey": "13273811",
            "employee": [
                {
                    "publicKey": "3030",
                    "mutkey": "13415424",
                    "formattedName": "V Vierde",
                    "contract": [
                        {
                            "publicKey": "1",
                            "mutkey": "13415424",
                            "functionName": "***NO FUNCTION NAME FOUND***"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "publicKey": "3040",
                    "mutkey": "13415426",
                    "formattedName": "V Vijfde",
                    "contract": [
                        {
                            "publicKey": "1",
                            "mutkey": "13415426",
                            "functionName": "***NO FUNCTION NAME FOUND***"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get into collection, f.e. an Array, every value for key functionName. Is there a way in Postman to do that?

Answer (score 2):

With this you can get each `functionName`:

```
const resBody = pm.response.json();

let employees = resBody.company[0].employee

let numberOfEmployees = employees.length

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfEmployees; i++){
    let functionName = employees[i].contract[0].functionName;
    console.log(functionName);
    // your code here
}
```