# How do I extract specific value from an array and assigned those value to a variable to use it in next postman request

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

I am kinda new when writing JavaScript for the postman. I want to extract only the `id` number which is dynamic and changes with every time I send a request to the server. So I want to extract and assigned those to a variable that I want to use in my next postman delete request. Not sure how it does this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[{
  "id": 2286288,
  "tradeIt": true,
  "productId": 2066275,
  "accountId": 2805,

}, {
  "id": 2286290,
  "tradeIt": true,
  "productId": 2066275,
  "accountId": 2804,

}, {
  "id": 2286289,
  "tradeIt": true,
  "productId": 2066275,
  "accountId": 2806,

}, {
  "id": 2286291,
  "tradeIt": true,
  "productId": 2066275,
  "accountId": 2808,
  "assetId": 0,
}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postman Testing - JSON - iterate over response with duplicate keys with different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847129/postman-testing-json-iterate-over-response-with-duplicate-keys-with-differen)

Answer (score -1):

if this is an array you should call the array itself with the index of the object you want

````
//let's say 
arr = [[{ "id": 2286288, "tradeIt": true, "productId": 2066275, "accountId": 2805,

}, {
    "id": 2286290,
    "tradeIt": true,
    "productId": 2066275,
    "accountId": 2804,

}, {
    "id": 2286289,
    "tradeIt": true,
    "productId": 2066275,
    "accountId": 2806,    

}, {
    "id": 2286291,
    "tradeIt": true,
    "productId": 2066275,
    "accountId": 2808,
    "assetId": 0,
}
]

//to return for example id 2286291
let index =3;
arr[index].id;```
````